# How to print only last column's string length of 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java

```
public class Arraysexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a[][] = new String[3][2];
        a[0][0] = "100";
        a[0][1] = "vipin";
        a[1][0] = "200";
        a[1][1] = "kamboj";
        a[2][0] = "300";
        a[2][1] = "true";
        int i = 0;
        int j=0;

        for (i=0; i <= 2; i++) {
            for (j=0; j <= 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");                        
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

100 vipin
200 kamboj
300 true
```

I want length of 'Vipin', 'Kamboj', and 'true' only in the same line.  In short, i want the below output:

```
100 vipin 5
200 kamboj 6
300 true 3
```

Comment: Note: `true` as a string has a length of _4_, not 3.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change `System.out.print(a[i][j]+ " ");` to `System.out.print(a[i][j]+ (j == a[i].length-1?" " + a[i][j].length() + " ":" "));`
Its means if `j == a[i].length-1` so print `" " + a[i][j].length() + " "` and if not print `" "`.

Answer (score 3):

You may try adding an additional print statement to output the length of the final column in each row:

```java
for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");    
    }
    System.out.println(a[i][a[i].length - 1].length());
}
```

This prints:

```
100 vipin 5
200 kamboj 6
300 true 4
```

Note that I am not hard-coding the two dimensions of the 2D string array.  Rather, I check for the row and column bounds dynamically, so the above solution should work for a 2D array of any dimensions.

Comment: thanks.. this is working correctly for me. I was also trying to get solution with column bounds dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<=1;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+ " ");                     
            }
            System.out.print(a[i][1].length()) // << add this
            System.out.println();
        }
```